# Lithium return json response with request header accept:application/json

Tags: php, json, lithium

I have a lithium app and I try to return json response when the header request has `Accept:application/json` (I would like to avoid using the type parameter in my route)

I add this instruction in my app/bootstrap/media.php but I still have a html response

```
Media::type('json', array('application/json'), array(
    'conditions' => array('type' => true)
));
```

What did I miss ?

I saw a similar question but it seams that the framework evolved : [PHP lithium(li3) how to set up automatic response with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756471/php-lithiumli3-how-to-set-up-automatic-response-with-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because content negotiation involves some overhead, it is not enabled by default. To enable it, simply add the following to your controller:

```
protected function _init() {
    $this->_render['negotiate'] = true;
    parent::_init();
}
```

Also, you don't need the `Media` configuration, as JSON is configured by default.